# Pinescript, How to code a conditional trigger?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

So I've got a trigger for a buy alert, which is when RSI is say < 20 and when price closes below the lowest of 3 EMA's. My problem is in trying to code for the 'lowest' of 3 EMA's.

Using a:

buyzone = ema1 < ema2 ? ema2 < ema3 : ema1 : na : na

Will get me buyzone = ema1 when they're in order of 3, 2, 1 top to bottom - but how would I translate that to a buy condition?

I tried the above code but when I trigger a buy, I cannot use a boolean string and it does not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `math.min()` to find out the lowest EMA value. Then use `ta.crossunder()` on that to find the cross.

```
lowest_ma = math.min(ema1, ema2, ema3)
is_lowest_ma_crossed = ta.crossunder(close, lowest_ma)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there a way I can call upon other values in that sequence? Say if I wanted to also call on the 2nd lowest?

Comment: There is a way to do it but please ask a new question for that. You should ask one question per post. You can accept this as an answer if it answers your question and then we can move on to the next question.